# Change a javascript syntax from ids to classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

From a jQuery gallery lightbox I have in html, the #imageGallery id

I want to have severals lightboxes so I changed the id to class, both in html and css.

How can I change it in javasctipt ?
I have this code refering to the particulart id :

```
var glength = $('#imageGallery li').length;
$('#imageGallery a').click( function(event)
$('#imageGallery a').not(this).removeClass('active')
('#imageGallery li').first().find('img').trigger('click')
$('#imageGallery li').last().find('img').trigger('click');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `.` for class `#` for id .. `#imageGallery` to `.imageGallery`

Answer (score 1):

use `.` for class `#` for id .. `#imageGallery` to `.imageGallery` this is just for how to select class .. but I'm sure you'll need a lot of things to make the code works for several lightboxes .. see the next code may help

```
$('.imageGallery a').click( function(event){   // when click on <a>
  var Get_Lis = $(this).closest('.imageGallery').find('li'); // get the li's in the same `imageGallery`
  var glength = Get_Lis.length; // get number of li's
  $(this).closest('.imageGallery').find('a').not(this).removeClass('active'); // change all but this
  Get_Lis.first().find('img').trigger('click');  // for first li
  Get_Lis.last().find('img').trigger('click');   // for last li
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I made these changes but there is something more needed. This is the javascript code I want to change to javascript (to long to full post it here) https://codepen.io/olivertaylor/pen/oxQYNm